# preg_replace php image messup

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to get the bbcode image to work. But i have problems with it.

what in the code is wrong and why?

I have this input:

```
[img]http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg[/img]
```

and would like it to be:

```
<img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg">
```

but the result is:

**`Q: How can i make this work properly?**

Full code:

```
 function parsebb($body,$userid = false, $user2 = false) {
            $find = array(
                "@\n@",
                "@[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]@is",
                "/\[url\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is",
                "/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/is",
                "/\[i\](.+?)\[\/i\]/is",
                "/\[u\](.+?)\[\/u\]/is",
                "/\[farge\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/farge\]/is",
                "/\[size\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/size\]/is",
                "/\[font\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/font\]/is",
                "/\[boks\=venstre\](.+?)\[\/boks\]/is",
                "/\[boks\=hoyre\](.+?)\[\/boks\]/is",
                "/\[boks\=midten\](.+?)\[\/boks\]/is",
                "/\[img\](.+?)\[\/img\]/is",
                "/\[email\](.+?)\[\/email\]/is",
                "/\[midten\](.+?)\[\/midten\]/is",
                "/\[venstre\](.+?)\[\/venstre\]/is",
                "/\[hoyre\](.+?)\[\/hoyre\]/is",
            );

            $replace = array(
                "<br />",
                "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",
                "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>",
                "<strong>$1</strong>",
                "<em>$1</em>",
                "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">$1</span>",
                "<font color=\"$1\">$2</font>",
                "<font size=\"$1\">$2</font>",
                "<span style=\"font-family: $1\">$2</span>",
                "<div align=\"left\" style=\"text-align:center; width:50%; \">$1</div>",
                "<div align=\"right\" style=\"text-align:center; width:50%;\">$1</div>",
                "<div align=\"center\" style=\"text-align:center; width:50%;\">$1</div>",
                "<img src=\"$1\">",
                "<a href=\"mailto:$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>",
                "<div style=\"text-align:center;\">$1</div>",
                "<div style=\"text-align:left;\">$1</div>",
                "<div style=\"text-align:right;\">$1</div>",


            );


                $body = htmlspecialchars($body);
                $body = preg_replace($specialCodes, $specialCodesReplace, $body);




            return $body;
        }
```

Comment: There are a lot of bbcode parsers out there.

Comment: Also, use some other delimiter; like `~` or `@` instead of `/`.

Comment: The problem is at your `"@[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]@is",` pattern even [img] ... [/img]  is matching with it just comment them and try again you will see it will be repleaced in well form or put this pattern line to the end of the array

Comment: santas helper. Please say that as answer and i will accept :3

Comment: Your server will get overloaded with such regex, also, you may consider using `preg_quote` instead of escaping every single block of code.

Comment: You should use CSS classes instead of inline styles.

Comment: @PedroLobito can you provide example?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Example?

Comment: Instead of using `<div align=\"center\" style=\"text-align:center; width:50%;\">$1</div>` as replacement string, use for example `<div class="center">$1</div>` and define the CSS class `.center` (try to find an other name:) in a separate file. Two advantages of doing this: 1) your html code will be shorter. 2) the day you want to change how messages look like, you only need to edit the css classes.

Comment: @maria http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: @maria look at my library designed to handle shortcodes: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . If you need any help with it, just open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at your

```
"@[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]@is"
```

pattern, even [img] ... [/img] is matching with it just, comment them and try again, it will be repleaced in well form or put this pattern line to the end of the array